# python Kivy: Button triggering event

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

so I have this login app that I made with a tutorial in youtube but the thing is I dont know what to put in the on_press in the kivy file. (The thing I need help with is at the end of the kivy file, it has a # next to it)
Python file:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class LoginApp(MDApp):
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def build(self):
        return 

    def btn(self):
        if self.username.text == 'karouma77' and self.password.text == '123':
            print('JOE MAMA ACCEPTS')

LoginApp().run()
```

Kivy file:

```
# Creating the screen:

MDScreen:
    md_bg_color: (35/255,59/255,54/255,1)
    username: username
    password: password

    MDCard:
        size_hint: None,None
        size: 320,400
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
        elevation: 15
        md_bg_color: (35/255,49/255,48/255,1)
        padding: 20
        spacing: 30
        orientation: 'vertical'
        # Adding items to the card:

        MDLabel:
            text: 'LOGIN'
            halign: 'center'
            font_style: 'H3'
            bold: True
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            padding_y: 15

        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: username
            hint_text: 'username'
            icon_right: 'account'
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 220
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
            color_active: (1,1,1,1)

        MDTextFieldRound:
            id: password
            hint_text: 'password'
            icon_right: 'eye-off'
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 220
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
            password: True
            color_active: (1,1,1,1)

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            text: 'SIGN-UP'
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
            font_size: 15
            on_press: # here Idk what to put here

        Widget:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
```

Thank you in advance!

Ignore this cause they wanted me to add  more details and idk what to add XDDXDX
so yeah um I really hope this post reaches ppl and  hope the answer fast I suppose...btw if anyone is reading this:
1- sorry for bad english
2- I hope you have a happy and long life
3- take care and adios XD

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
        on_press: app.btn(username, password)
```

And modify the `btn()` method as:

```
def btn(self, username, password):
    if username.text == 'karouma77' and password.text == '123':
        print('JOE MAMA ACCEPTS')
```